# How to escape ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, arrays

I was curious to know how I can save myself falling from this exception,i.e how would I get-rid of it in general at least in java.

Comment: show us the code that is failing

Answer (score 4):

Use iterators or enhanced for-loops to abstract away the explicit use of array indexes:

```
Iterator<Object> myIterator = Arrays.asList(arrayOfObjects).iterator();
while(myIterator.hasNext()) {
    doSomething(myIterator.next());
}
```

or

```
for(Object o : arrayOfObjects) {
    doSomething(o);
}
```

---

Update:  you've updated the question; now it has an `ArrayList`.  Iterators and enhanced for-loops work with `ArrayList`s (and many other collections), too:

```
for(Question myQuestion : q) {
    doSomethingWithAQuestion(myQuestion);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
List<Object> list = getListOfUnknownSize();
while(list != null && i < list.size()) {
    process(list.get(i));
    i++;
}
```

Comment: FYI, you could just process the elements in the list without counting them, e.g. `for(Object o : getListOfUnkownSize()) { process(o); }`

Comment: @matsev I know. MattFenwick covered that one, though. I was just giving options. The perl way ;-)